# working with factors in R

Tags: r, replace, dataframe

I have a data.frame of factors in R. I need to replace one value with a string, should be simple, but I keep getting an error I don't understand. heres what the data.frame looks like..

```
'data.frame':   13 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ Date...Time: Factor w/ 6 levels "9/25 8:25 ET",..: 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 4 ...
 $ Favorite   : Factor w/ 13 levels "At Baltimore",..: 8 11 10 2 3 1 4 5 6 7 ...
 $ Spread     : Factor w/ 7 levels "-1.5","-12","-2",..: 4 5 3 4 7 4 1 7 2 5 ...
 $ Underdog   : Factor w/ 13 levels "At Chicago","At Dallas",..: 8 NA 1 4 12 5 6 11 7 10 ...
```

I am trying to manipulate one value in this data.frame using this code..

```
dat[2,4] = "String"
```

but when I do this I get this error message

```
    Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iseq, value = "String") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
```

A 'NA' is generated, How would I go about replacing that 'NA' value with a string? Please help I'm new with R. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `levels` function to alter the levels of a factor. For example, say you have this `data.frame`:

```
dat <- data.frame(
  x=rep(letters[1:3],2),
  y=rep(LETTERS[1:3],2),
  stringsAsFactors=TRUE)
##
R> dat
  x y
1 a A
2 b B
3 c C
4 a A
5 b B
6 c C
```

and you want to change `dat[2,2]` to `"string"` from `"B"`. If you want to change *only* this particular observation (and not all occurrences of `"B"` in the variable `y`), you can add a level and then reassign:

```
levels(dat[,2]) <- c(levels(dat[,2]),"string")
dat[2,2] <- "string"
##
R> dat
  x      y
1 a      A
2 b string
3 c      C
4 a      A
5 b      B
6 c      C
```

If you want to change *all* occurrences of `"B"` to `"string"`, you can just do

```
levels(dat[,2])[which(levels(dat[,2])=="B")] <- "string"
R> dat
  x      y
1 a      A
2 b string
3 c      C
4 a      A
5 b string
6 c      C
```

Answer (score 0):

All columns of your data frame are of class `factor`. If you want to treat the column `Underdog` as a `character` column, you can transform it with

```
dat$Underdog <- as.character(dat$Underdog)
```

Then you can change the value:

```
dat[2, "Underdog"] <- "String"
```

Comment: just figured it out on my own, this was the ticket. Thank you